Structure of pores of tinder fungus
I’m interested in various natural structures: fractals, packing, hyperuniformity etc.
Here is photo of pores of tinder fungus or Fomes fomentarius:

The pore distribution is neither hexagonal packing nor purely random.
I see strange patterns like large circles.
Is there any information on the pore geometry?
What is the pattern?

I've had a rummage around on google scholar and there's some truly bizarre papers out there related to this fungus, but nothing like what you're asking. The folks on our [bioinformatics.se] site may just have access to resources not listed. Perhaps you could try there.

You do have to remember that our brains are very good at finding patterns even if there aren't any. It looks fairly random to me, but I have no data to back that up. I don't even know how you would go about a randomness analysis in this case.

A vague idea popped into my head, a suspicion that the [astronomy.se] site might have knowledge of software that could perform exactly the kind of analysis you're looking for. I've no idea how to phrase the question to be on-topic there mind you. Same goes for our [dsp.se] site. In fact, having glanced at their site, I'd bet on the latter.
